# Can i write html on one line only in my php code?

Tags: php, html

i need to embed a html 301 redirect in my php code and i wanted to save chars in my html.
 Can i write HTML on one line since it is parsed? Is there anything against this practice?

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head><body><h1>Moved Permanently</h1><p>The document has moved <a href="<?php echo $location ?>">here</a>.</p></body></html>
<?
```

thank you

Comment: Yes, a lot of sites run their html, css & javascript through minimizers that remove unnecessary whitespace (and do other optimizations). The result looks mostly like this. Though I don't see why you would care about those few bytes in this specific case.

Comment: Premature optimization :)

Answer (score 1):

Your single-line HTML snippet will work fine. Improperly written browsers could conceivably choke on one-liners that exceed ridiculous maximum lengths, but in practice something like your snippet should not pose any problem.

Of course, since you work in PHP anyway, my preferred way of handling redirections would be something like:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com");
?>
```

But that's up to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The general practice is to redirect to an error page whose name is based on the type of error code, for instance a 301 redirect would be called 301.html.  You can pass url parameters for the location and [you could use a small javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter) to extract these parameter values.  The reason why you should generally use html rather than php is that html is more robust, and should there be serious problems with the server, at least if the server can still serve static files, the errors should still work as expected.

If readability is your issue, putting this page in its own file is as best as you can hope for.  You can fully expand the html in its own page, so it is readable, yet it is also equally functional.  If optimization is your concern, this is *not* the approach you should take.  There are plenty of libraries in php that will compact these files for you.  In the long run, it is not worth it to you to try to squeeze everything into one line, even for a page that isn't likely to change.